# How to implement a syntax analyzer for a chatbot?

Tags: parsing, nlp, chatbot

I am actually trying to make a simple chatbot for information retrieval purposes in slack using python and I have come up with a Context Free Grammar (CFG) for synatx check . Now that I have a grammar, I want to create a parsing table/ parse tree for this grammar to validate my input string. It would be really helpful if you could let me know some libraries/ links/ mateirals that can help me implement a parser to perform syntax check for my chatbot.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already wrote a context-free grammar, you can use the ChartParser of NLTK to parse any input, as described here: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html

I think, however, that a hand written grammar will not be robust enough to deal with the huge amount of variations your users could write. These have gone out of fashion decades ago due to their poor performance and in constituency parsing one rather uses treebanks to generate grammars.

Depending on what exactly you want to archive, I suggest you also take a look at a dependency parser e.g. from [spaCy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#navigating). They are faster and allow you to easily navigate from the predicate of the sentence to its subject and objects.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @jgontrum. I get the point to use treebanks but in my case on a primitive level, normal bottom-up parsing will help. I also wondered as to whether NLTK provides any libraries to implement semantic analysis to the grammar as well?